# Which PHP web service API should I use for WSDL?

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl

I want to write a PHP web service client for 
[XML](http://topup.sparrowsms.com/wsdl/?wsdl).

Per my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29042797/php-soap-wsdl-aut-with-header-error), I'm using `SoapClient`. Is this correct?

Comment: I rewrote your question and title pretty thoroughly to eliminate redundancy, unclear phrasing, and the parts that overlap with your other question. I also added a useful tag and reformatted it. Hopefully I've correctly understood your intention to make a web services *client*, as opposed to some sort of mirror or proxy or wrapper that would itself be a web service.

Comment: you 're right , thank you  :) i hope this changes it helps to me

Answer (score 0):

Manage WSDL in PHP could be very complicated, the best solution I could suggest is to use a framework that could handle all with an object oriented structure.

Have a look to [Web Service Framework](https://github.com/wso2/wsf/tree/master/php)

Comment: i see this scripts it seems nice but i don't find it in wsdl mode in these script who authentication with header :( and i think so many way to get result just show me a sample thank you

Comment: Sometimes providing an URL to a WSDL file that  is protected with HTTP authentication don't work. Try to download WSDL locally.

Comment: do you see my question linked ? [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29042797/php-soap-wsdl-aut-with-header-error [link] it's not http authentication anymore , i must use to send token access in header at first time , but don't know how send these array :(